# How to get image for asciimath formula when form submitted

Tags: php, tinymce, asciimath

I'm using asciimath plugin for tinyMCE which creates image when Tex formula is entered. But when I submit the form instead of image created only formula entered gets posted, I need the image created and need to save in the database.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using this plugin is to eliminate the need to generate images.

Instead, you can use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), a free and open source JavaScript display engine to convert this formula back to an image.

Comment: Thank you, but can't find any MathJax plugin for tinyMCE. How to integrate it?

Comment: It's not a plugin for TinyMCE... It's a javascript display engine you use to work the other way around: to display it on your website (instead of using images).